Are path-connected LOTS also locally path-connected?
According to https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000522 (which cites Theorem 24.1 of https://zbmath.org/0951.54001 ) every connected linearly ordered topological space (LOTS) is also locally connected.
It seems that similarly, every path-connected LOTS is also locally path-connected. Is this easy to see?
(In fact, I conjecture that every path-connected LOTS is a subinterval of the two-sided long line, that is, two copies of the long ray quotiented at their initial points.)

If I am not mistaken the path connected Lots are some connected subspace of the long line. The proof is a bit tedious.

Yes to your first question:
Let $\le$ be a linear order on $X$ with order topology $\tau$
such that $(X, \tau)$ is path-connected.
Let $x, y \in X, x < y$.
Then there is a map $\psi: [0, 1] \rightarrow [x, y]$, which is
an order isomorphism and a homeomorphism.
PROOF.
Since $X$ is path-connected and $T_2$, there is a (topological) embedding $\psi: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$
with $\psi(0) = x, \psi(1) = y$. Hence, $\psi$ is not decreasing.
Since $[0,1]$ is a connected LOTS and $\psi$ is continuous and injective, it is strictly increasing.
Hence $\psi([0, 1]) \subset [x, y]$.
Moreover, by the intermediate value theorem, $\psi$ is surjective, hence $\psi$ is an order isomorphism.
Therefore, it is also a homeomorphism.
(With respect to the order topology on $[x,y]$, but this is the same as the subspace topology, since $[x,y]$ is convex.)
In particular, if $|X| \neq 1$, by the above, each element has a neighborhood, which is homeomorphic to the closed unit interval. Hence, it is locally path-connected.

I take back my earlier comment: I agree that $T_2$ with path connected implies arc connected.

@StevenClontz path-connected Hausdorff spaces are arc-connected, this is a non-trivial result and follows from topological characterization of the unit interval. Mazurkiewicz theorem says that any completely metrizable, connected, locally connected, separable space is arc-connected (perhaps separable is not needed). Since image of a locally connected compact space is locally connected, given a path $p:[0, 1]\to X$ where $p(0)\neq p(1)$, the image $p([0, 1])$ has all of those properties, so you can find an arc from $p(0)$ to $p(1)$ in it.

Building on Ulli's answer, here is a proof of the conjectured form for path connected LOTS.

Proposition: Every path connected LOTS is order-isomorphic (and hence also homeomorphic) to a convex subset (connected subspace) of the two-sided long line.

Notation: The long ray is the ordered space $L=\omega_1\times[0,1)$ with the lexicographic order and the corresponding order topology.  $[0,1)$ is the half-open interval in $\mathbb R$.  As an ordered set, the two-sided long line is obtained from $L^*$ (a copy of $L$ with the reverse order) followed by $L$ and identifying $\max(L^*)$ and $\min(L)$.
Proof of Proposition: Suppose $(X,<)$ is a linearly ordered set with a corresponding order topology that is path connected.  We can assume wlog that $X$ contains at least two points.  Let $a$ be a point of $X$ which is neither the minimum nor the maximum of $X$.  We'll show that the set $[a,\rightarrow)\subseteq X$ is order-isomorphic to an initial segment of the long ray $L$.  Then, by symmetry, $(\leftarrow,a]$ will be a final segment of $L^*$ and one will be able to conclude that $X$ is order-isomorphic to some convex subset of the two-sided long line.
So we assume now that $X$ has a minimum element $a$.
If $X$ has a maximum element $b$, by Ulli's result the interval $[a,b]\subseteq X$ is order-isomorphic to the interval $[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$, which is an initial segment of $L$.
Otherwise, $X$ has infinite cofinality.  There is a strictly increasing (transfinite) sequence of points $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ in $X$, cofinal in $X$, with the ordinal $\lambda$ as small as possible.  $\lambda$ must be a regular cardinal.  And we can also assume the map $\alpha\mapsto a_\alpha$ is continuous; i.e., if $\xi$ is a limit ordinal $<\lambda$, then $a_\xi=\sup_{\alpha<\xi}a_\alpha$. (See for example here.)
If $\lambda\ge\omega_2$, then $\omega_1<\lambda$ and hence the interval $[a,a_{\omega_1}]\subseteq X$ is order-isomorphic to $[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$.  But this is impossible as the uncountably many open intervals $(a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1})$ for $0\le\alpha<\omega_1$ are pairwise disjoint, but the interval $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$ has the countable chain condition.  So $\lambda=\omega$ or $\lambda=\omega_1$.
Let $A=\{a_\alpha:\alpha<\lambda\}\subseteq L$.
Claim: Each point $x\in L\setminus A$ belongs to a unique open interval $(a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1})$.
Proof of claim: By cofinality, there is some $a_\beta>x$, so take the smallest such $a_\beta$.  The index $\beta$ cannot be a limit ordinal because otherwise $a_\beta=\sup_{\alpha<\beta}a_\alpha$ and there would be some $\alpha<\beta$ with $x<a_\alpha$, contradicting that $a_\beta$ was the smallest possible.  Hence $\beta$ is a successor ordinal $\alpha+1$ and $x\in(a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1})$.
Therefore, $X$ is the union of all the half-open intervals $[a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1})$, which are pairwise disjoint.  Since each interval $[a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1}]$ is order-isomorphic to $[0,1]$, each of the half-open intervals is order-isomorphic to $[0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$.  Pasting together an order-isomorphism for each of these intervals shows that $(X,<)$ is order-isomorphic to $\lambda\times[0,1)$ with its lexicographic order.
Finally, if $\lambda=\omega$, the lexicographic order on $\omega\times[0,1)$ is order-isomorphic to the interval $[0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$ (consider a increasing sequence $(a_n)_n$ converging to 1).  And if $\lambda=\omega_1$, the lexicographic order on $\omega_1\times[0,1)$ is the long ray.
This completes the proof.

As a consequence, up to order-isomorphism, the full list of linearly ordered sets with a path connected order topology is as follows:

the empty set
a singleton
$[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$
$[0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $(0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$ (these two are homeomorphic)
$(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$
the long ray $L$ and its reverse $L^*$ (these two are homeomorphic)
the open long ray ($L$ without its minimum) and its reverse (these two are homeomorphic)
the two-sided long line


Great result! :)

Minor correction: those are linearly ordered sets with path-connected order topology. Partial orders are more rich than that.

@tomasz Thanks, of course.  I'll make the clarification.

Very nice proof (+1). One minor remark: $(a_\alpha){\alpha<\lambda}$ should be strictly increasing (which, of course, is no problem). This will guarantee that $(a\alpha,a_{\alpha+1})$ is non-empty.

@Ulli Thanks.  I was using increasing in the sense of "strictly increasing" (vs. "non-decreasing).  It's always a little confusing in English what is meant exactly by "increasing".  But I'll clarify to be completely unambiguous.

Ulli's answer essentially proves that an injective path from $a$ to $b$ is an order-preserving homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$ for $a<b$. But to obtain an injective path does not seem to be trivial for me. In fact I hadn't heard of the concept of arc-connectedness until yesterday, let alone the related results. So I'm giving a direct proof here, only using the path-connectedness and what is taught in first-year analysis:
We want to show that every convex subset of a path-connected LOTS $X$ is again path-connected to obtain the local path-connectedness of $X$, and it suffices to show that $[a,b]$ is path-connected for $a<b$. Pick a path $\gamma$ in $X$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$. Note that $\{t\in[0,1]:\gamma(t)\le a\}$ is a non-empty closed subset of $[0,1]$, so it has a maximum element $t_0<1$, and by definition $\gamma(t_0)\le a$. Can the inequality be strict? No, because otherwise the intermediate value theorem would give us some $t_0'\in(t_0,1)$ such that $\gamma(t'_0) = a$, contradicting the maximality of $t_0$. Similarly, set $t_1=\min\{t\in[\color{red}{t_0},1]:\gamma(t)\ge b\}$, then $t_1>t_0$, and $\gamma(t_1)=b$. The numbers $t\in(t_0,t_1)$ must have $\gamma(t)>a$ (because of the maximality of $t_0$) and $\gamma(t)<b$ (because of the minimality of $t_1$), so $\gamma|_{[t_0,t_1]}$ is a path from $a$ and $b$ lying solely in $[a,b]$.
In case you would have any doubt about the intermediate value theorem in LOTS, please consult Theorem 24.3 of Topology by Munkres.

I like this proof, simple and to the point.

@PatrickR Thanks! :)

@JianingSong please refer to my comment under Ulli's answer. This is a non-trivial result, but a true result.

@Jakobian Very great, thanks for the comment!
